# Can we use one volume/shared volume as root volume for multiple EC2 instances in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a use case to maintain 2 servers, primary and secondary. Use secondary if the primary fails/stops. Only one server can be used at a time. The primary has a lot of activity going on with it, like installation and multiple read-writes. In order to replicate this to the secondary I'll have to create timely snapshots and then restore them when required. In order to skip this, can't I use a shared volume for both the servers, so that I can use the secondary without first having to restore a snapshot from the primary server? I've read about **EBS** volume type, **io2** which supports multi-attach wherein as the name suggests can be attached to multiple instances and used as shared volume, which can't be done with other volume types. Will this create some kind of issue like data corruption if used as root volume. *Don't want to use NFS/EFS as it is not compatible with the application I use.*

**This is AWS specific**

Comment: From the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volumes-multi.html): "Multi-Attach enabled volumes can't be created as boot volumes."

Comment: Why do you need to multi-attach the root volume? Are you able to use a non-root EBS volume to store your app data - in which case you can multi-attach that volume to primary and secondary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an EBS volume for your multi-attach app data needs.

One of the reasons you can’t multi-attach a root volume is that these root volumes are disposed of when an EC2 instance is terminated. AWS recommends that app data is not stored on the root volume due to the ephemeral nature of the root volumes.

AWS documentation for root volumes can be found here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/RootDeviceStorage.html

I recommend mounting a second volume for your app data.